# How to mirror linux pc screen to android over usb

Tags: linux, usb, display, android, mirroring

I have an android tablet and a linux laptop running manjaro (KDE), I managed to use my android tablet as a fully functional second monitor by creating a virtual display and streaming it over wifi with Deskreen, but it lags sometimes and there is a noticable ping. I guess wired connection will fix all the problems I am expiriencing so I want to stream my virtual display to an android tablet over usb (probably to some app), I was doing exactly that on windows with Duet display about 4 years ago so I think its entirely possible on linux too. Does anybody know if there is an open source alternative of Duet display for linux or proprietary one but still free to use without optional paid fetures?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I don't think you need a different software. Enabling adb on device and installing Android SDK on PC side allows you to perform port forwarding via adb (through USB).